How do I properly handle exceptions in Python without losing the traceback information?
I'm working on a Python application where I need to gracefully handle exceptions and log useful information for debugging purposes. Specifically, I want to catch exceptions that occur during runtime, but I also need to preserve the traceback information (the stack trace) to understand where the error originated from and how the exception propagates.
I know that Python provides a try-except block to catch exceptions, but I want to ensure that:
I catch and handle exceptions properly.
I log the full traceback of the error without losing any critical debugging information.
I still provide meaningful output (perhaps to the user) while logging all relevant information for further debugging.
I’ve seen that when I catch exceptions using a simple except block, sometimes the full traceback is lost or not logged properly. I want to make sure I can log the full stack trace in a structured way for easy debugging.
I’ve used basic try-except blocks in my code, but I’m not sure if I'm logging the traceback effectively.
I tried using the logging module, but I’m not sure how to include the full traceback.
I understand that the traceback can be retrieved using traceback.format_exc(), but I’m unclear on how to implement this correctly with proper logging.
Example of what I’ve done (but it doesn’t seem to log everything):
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

def risky_function():
    # Simulating an error
    x = 1 / 0

try:
    risky_function()
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("An error occurred: %s", e)


In the example above, the exception is caught, and an error message is logged, but the full traceback information is not included in the log. I need to preserve and log the full traceback in my logs for better debugging.
What I am looking for:
An example of how to properly catch exceptions in Python and log the full traceback using the logging module or other methods.
A clear explanation of how to use traceback and logging together to log detailed information, including the error message and the full stack trace.
Best practices for logging exceptions, ensuring that both the exception message and traceback are captured without losing critical information.

If you are handling the exception properly, you don't need the traceback. Your example doesn't handle the exception; it just logs that it happens. If your program can continue in the face of the error, thats's probably all you need. If not, you should reraise the exception to let someone else handle it, or in the worst case let your program terminate.

logging.exception behaves like logging.error, but also prints information (including the traceback) about the current exception.
try:
    risky_function()
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception("An error occurred: %s", e)

